# Is it in any way possible to get the asp:menu items separated in multiple-columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, multiple-columns, aspmenu

Is there any way to get the asp:menu items separated into multiple columns? I get the menu items from a System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider and then "forward" them to a SiteMap to be used with the asp:menu.
I need a menu structured like:

```
Item1 Item5 Item9  Item11
Item2 Item6 Item10 Item12
Item3 Item7 Item11 Item13
Item4 Item8 Item12 Item14
```

And so on.. 
How do i achive this based on a System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider?

Answer (score 0):

When you using asp menu it comes to client side in different view as shown below.

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    <table>
```

As you can see that it is not possible to divide one row in two, so technically it is not possible using single asp menu control. 
Other way is to use two different Asp menu control.
And if it is possible as you ask here than I love to see that code.